# Can I use something like exist in inner join?

Tags: postgresql

when i use the below query it doesn't show other data when any of the inner joins are not found. how can i overcome this problem

```
SELECT 
unit_name,demand_name,unit_position_name,demand_category_name
FROM process 
INNER JOIN unit ON process.fk_unit_id = unit_id
INNER JOIN unit_position  ON process.fk_unit_position_id = unit_position_id
INNER JOIN demand_category ON process.fk_demand_category_id = demand_category_id
INNER JOIN demand_type ON process.fk_demand_type_id = demand_type_id
INNER JOIN demand ON process.fk_demand_id = demand_id;
```

Comment: That's what a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is used for. But use it only where you need it.